# How do I upload to pypi website using command line?

Tags: python

I get an 403 error saying that "you are not allowed to store 'tester' package information" when I try to upload my package to pypi.

I use the command `c:\user\python3.exe setup.py register` on windows and `python3 setup.py register` on linux and get the same error.

I have registered to the pypi website, and confirmed to the confirmation link that was provided to my email. I don't know what the fault is. What is being done wrong here?

EDIT:
from distutils.core import setup

```
setup(
name = 'tester',
version = '1.0.1',
py_modules = ['tester'],
author = 'lind',
author_email = 'lind@gmail.com',
url = 'http://www.lindl.com',
description = 'A simple printer of nested lists',
)
```

At first I made the tester package, but as per the suggestion, I built the `recursive` package and then the `test package. The packages 
[have built accurately](https://pasteboard.co/cP2cZ5MBs.png)(here the dist folder appears empty but it contains the zip file inside), but it gives me [This specific error](https://pasteboard.co/cP6dranI2.png)

Comment: there's also package called [`nester`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nester/1.1.0), go and find out unique name, you can use `lind` for example

Answer (score 3):

well, it is because there is already package called [`tester`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tester/1.0.0) and it looks like you are not its owner

you need to give another, unique name to your package

Comment: still the same thing, with three different names, I tried, but this error keeps popping on and on, any other suggestions?

Comment: @lind: add your `setup.py` to question

Comment: I've added it to the question, my original one.

Comment: @lind: what names have you tried? add to question please and error tracebacks as well